# Group share permisssions to windows clients?

Tags: samba, permissions

On our home network we have Ubuntu 10.4 amd64 Desktop functioning as a file server and a couple of WinXP laptops. Ubuntu is not set up as a domain server, user names and passwords are synched, manually, across all machines.

What is the proper way to set up a shared space for the windows clients so that members of group Parents, and only Parents, both have read and write access to it's contents?

I thought I had this done, but when Dad creates or writes a file in \server\share-parents\ Mom's write access to same is revoked, vice versa. This creates all sorts of havoc when said file is the family expense spreadsheet and the home renos are *this close* to blowing the year's budget and credit card payment is due... Need I add that last years kludge of recursively chown'ing to :parents and chmod'ing g+w no longer keeps the bacon out of the fire?

The smb.conf shared section:

```
[global]
# other stuff edited out
security = user

[share-parents]
comment = parents shared files
available = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
valid users = mom, dad
writable = yes
path=/home/shared
follow symlinks = yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a permission problem, which you can solve either by:

1) telling Samba to force some specific permissions (e.g., `664`) on
all files in the share: the relevant solution is discussed here:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/samba-share-permissions-57589/

It boils down to: assuming you want everything to be read+write for
"parents" and read-only for everyone else, add the following lines to
you `[parents]` share configuration:

```
  force create mode = 0664
  force security mode = 0664 
  force directory mode = 0775
```

Every bit set to `1` in one of the "force * mode", will be set by
SAMBA on the file, regardless of what the Windows clients requests.

2) Use the `security mask` setting to disallow clearing the
group-write bit (bits set to `1` in the "security mask" can be
manipulated by Windows clients):

```
   security mask = 757
```

So, once you've set a file `g+w` from Linux, it can never be changed
back from Windows.

A more detailed explanation of the relevant parameters is given at:
http://cri.ch/linux/docs/sk0002.html

Regardless of the chosen workaround, you might also want to force all
files in the share to belong to UNIX group `parents`:

```
  force group = parents
```

Either one of the two options should work; they are compatible so you can
also choose to implement both at the same time.

Comment: I chose the 2nd option.`force group` works for maintaining the group, thanks for that. `security mask` isn't working though, `g+w` is still being stripped when a file is saved. Or was I supposed to do both 1 and 2? (first sentence says "either")

Comment: @matt Either one should work, but they are not incompatible so you can also choose to apply both.